# Expected identifier but got 'payable'

Tags: blockchain, ether

Following is my code:

```
    pragma solidity >=0.4.17;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address payable [] public players;

    constructor () public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0.01 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, now, players)));
    }

    function pickWinner() public restricted {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        uint256 index = random() % players.length;
        players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
        players.length = 0;
    }

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

}
```

This code works fine in Remix editor. 
But getting error in VS code as follows:

Expected identifier but got 'payable'

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are running a different version of solidity compiler.

As https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/, the current version of solidity is 0.5.3